# error on line 1 at column 284: Extra content at the end of the document Error while download chart as a svg vector

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

When export this chart by svg format an error occur.
Error Like:
This page contains the following errors:
error on line 1 at column 284: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

[image]

[image]

Opening the image with Edge or Chrome results in the same error.

What Should I do to resolved this issue

Comment: Hi, your issue seems to be related to the following thread: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/16589

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to upgrade with latest highchart version

**^11.1.0** highchart version is working fine , previously I used ^9.3.3 which wasn't working above feature